# How to create a Virtual Machine in Microsoft Azure without PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) address?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, virtual-network

Is there any way to create a virtual machine without Public IP address in Windows Azure? 
Even if you are creating a VM in virtual network we cannot control the Public IP assigned by Azure. Is there any way to disable or delete the public IP assigned by Azure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is incorrect as of 11/29/2016 You can now choose in the provisioning stage through Azure portal to set the public IP Address as NONE. This will allow only communication within the virtual network that the VM is living in.

Answer (score 6):

No. A VM will always have Public IP Address. But you can **not** assign any [Endpoints](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) (leave the VM without any Endpoints defined) - this will effectively block all and any Internet traffic for your VM before it event reaches the Internal Data Centre network.

There will always be a Public IP address assigned to any Cloud Service with something deployed. It is up to you to decide whether to allow Internet traffic to your VM or not. And this decision is made via defining Endpoints.

**EDIT**

Using Azure Resource Manager you can create a VM without Public IP. You can control this setting on the Network Adapter. Within the IP Configurations for your Network Adapter in Azure Resource Manager you mus specify NONE for the Public IP Address setting.

Comment: Note, with the new azure Resource Manager, you do this through a network security group, not endpoints https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

Answer (score 2):

With the Resource Groups approach you can assign the public ip as None.

It'll still have a network interface, which can be used to access it within the virtual network.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled across this question via a post on Twitter and saw there wasn't a recent, complete, answer.

Nowadays it's possible to create a virtual machine in Azure without a Public IP address. Check out the sample below. It'll create a VM, a NIC, and a VNet where the VM will be created in.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
        "my-super-secure-password": {
            "type": "securestring"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "my-project-prefix-nic"
            ],
            "location": "westeurope",
            "name": "my-project-prefix",
            "properties": {
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": false
                    }
                },
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "Standard_D8ds_v4"
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces','my-project-prefix-nic')]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('my-super-secure-password')]",
                    "adminUsername": "jan",
                    "computerName": "my-project-prefix"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "dataDisks": [
                        {
                            "createOption": "Empty",
                            "diskSizeGB": 512,
                            "lun": 0,
                            "managedDisk": {
                                "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS"
                            },
                            "name": "my-project-prefix-datadisk-0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
                        "offer": "Windows-10",
                        "sku": "20h1-pro-g2",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "FromImage",
                        "diskSizeGB": 256,
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS"
                        },
                        "name": "my-project-prefix-osdisk"
                    }
                }
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "my-project-prefix-vnet"
            ],
            "location": "westeurope",
            "name": "my-project-prefix-nic",
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'my-project-prefix-vnet', 'my-project-prefix-subnet')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "name": "my-project-prefix-vnet",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "my-project-prefix-subnet",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                            "delegations": []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I'm omitting [the `publicIPAddress` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/networkinterfaces#networkinterfaceipconfigurationpropertiesformat-object) on creation of the VM. Seeing it's not a mandatory property, it's still a valid resource.